# hibernate + mysql + load data in file

Tags: mysql, hibernate, load-data-infile

Hi I am trying to load data from a file to Mysql DB using hibernate.

here is the query,

```
session.createSQLQuery("LOAD DATA INFILE E:/uploaded/NumSerie/NS/NumSerie.txt INTO TABLE prod CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;").executeUpdate();
```

But i get the following error,

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [LOAD DATA INFILE E:/uploaded/NumSerie/NS/NumSerie.txt INTO TABLE prod CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '
' IGNORE 1 LINES;]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterParser.parse(ParameterParser.java:92)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParamLocationRecognizer.parseLocations(ParamLocationRecognizer.java:75)
```

How can I rewrite this query so this is executed properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Satya, I tried that but it did not work :(

Comment: try this : LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a [parameterised query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930)

I'm no Hibernate guru but this could work:

```
session.createSQLQuery("LOAD DATA INFILE :file INTO TABLE prod CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;")
    .setString("file", "E:/uploaded/NumSerie/NS/NumSerie.txt")
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I'm glad :) For other users, the problem is the use of a colon in the query. Hibernate interprets this to mean there is a parameter in the query and fails to validate the parameter name. By using an actual parameter we can pass the path string directly to MySQL. This way Hibernate won't try to interpret the colon and fail.