# RESTful web services to load data infile MYSQL

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, rest, load-data-infile

I am trying to use RESTful web services to interact with MySQL database in Eclipse IDE and Glassfish server. Is it possible to execute statements like ***load data infile*** and ***into outfile*** through web services? The infile and outfile are in CSV format.If yes, it would be of great help if an example can be provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some kind of `ORM` like `Hibernate`, there is a way to do it. Visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351078/hibernate-mysql-load-data-in-file) to know more.