# Table column order generated by Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a table generated from an entity class by Hibernate, and the current order of this table is:

```
describe Context;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| context      | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| publish_time | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| URL          | varchar(400) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| term_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then this statement is configured to load data to database:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'context.txt' INTO TABLE Context FIELDS TERMINATED\ BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

However, the order of the 5 columns of the data file "context.txt" is different from the column order in the table. Because of that, I received this error message when the loading is initiated in the application with:

```
     20:46:00,207 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] 
    (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) HHH000388:  Unsuccessful: LOAD DATA 
LOCAL INFILE '/myproject/src/main/resources/context.txt' INTO TABLE Context FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            20:46:00,207 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`BombDS`.`Context`, CONSTRAINT `FK_afatp1vwi13k5r0hftr04vctl` FOREIGN KEY (`term_id`) REFERENCES `Term` (`id`))
```

If I can't change the order in the file, is there a way to control the column order generated by Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify the ordering of the columns from the file in the LOAD statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/blah/Desktop/something.csv' INTO TABLE
test.test_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
optionally ENCLOSED by '"' 
(id, name, count)
```

Comment: I got the same error, it only created the table, but can't load the data. Now I tried to load manually into the empty table created by Hibernate, i received this error message: ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: huh.  I use the LOAD statement quite frequently with no issues.  I'm not sure this is your problem. "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`BombDS`.`Context`, CONSTRAINT `FK_afatp1vwi13k5r0hftr04vctl` FOREIGN KEY (`term_id`) REFERENCES `Term` (`id`))" - makes it sound as if you have @Embeddable or @OneToOne/@OneToMany on a related table and it can't insert the data because another table has a shared id.

Comment: Yes. 'term_id' is a foreign key in Context, which references the primary key "id" in table Term.

Comment: I think that prevents the load because you're not actually persisting the data using JPA.  You're trying to load the data outside.  I think you need to parse the text file into your @Entity and then persist it into that table using EntityManager.

Comment: However, this works, I manually inserted one at command line: insert into Context (id,context,publish_time, URL,term_id) values (1,'lumia6 is sublime', '2016-03-04 1:06:15', 'http://url3.com',4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

Comment: However, this doesn't work, if I tried to load the same record in this file:  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myproject/src/main/resources/Context.txt' INTO TABLE Context FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'(id,context,publish_time,URL,term_id);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`BombwordDS`.`Context`, CONSTRAINT `FK_afatp1vwi13k5r0hftr04vctl` FOREIGN KEY (`term_id`) REFERENCES `Term` (`id`))

Comment: here's a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351078/hibernate-mysql-load-data-in-file

Comment: But this LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE indeed works with my other two tables, which don't have a foreign key as Context table has.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105472/discussion-between-user697911-and-neal).